# Drupal installation strange permission.

Tags: installation, file-permissions, fedora-17, drupal

I am trying to install drupal 7 im my Linux( Fedora 17) machine. I have given `chmod -R 755` permission to directory `/var/www/html/drupal`, additionally `go+w` to the same directory,recursively. But when I tried to install the drupal 7, it says

```
File system 
The directory sites/default/files does not exist. An automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.
```

But I have the `/sites/default/files` directory, which I created manually. `ls -l` for the directories are:

```
[root@localhost drupal]# ls -l
total 240
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  6553 Mar 31 06:43 authorize.php
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root 75229 Mar 31 06:43 CHANGELOG.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  1481 Mar 31 06:43 COPYRIGHT.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root   720 Mar 31 06:43 cron.php
drwxrwxrwx.  4 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 includes
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root   529 Mar 31 06:43 index.php
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  1451 Mar 31 06:43 INSTALL.mysql.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  1874 Mar 31 06:43 INSTALL.pgsql.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root   688 Mar 31 06:43 install.php
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  1298 Mar 31 06:43 INSTALL.sqlite.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root 17861 Mar 31 06:43 INSTALL.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root 18092 Mar 31 06:43 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  8191 Mar 31 06:43 MAINTAINERS.txt
drwxrwxrwx.  4 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 misc
drwxrwxrwx. 42 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 modules
drwxrwxrwx.  5 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 profiles
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  5376 Mar 31 06:43 README.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  1561 Mar 31 06:43 robots.txt
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 scripts
drwxrw-rw-.  4 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 sites
drwxrwxrwx.  7 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:43 themes
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root 19416 Mar 31 06:43 update.php
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  9642 Mar 31 06:43 UPGRADE.txt
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  2051 Mar 31 06:43 web.config
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root   417 Mar 31 06:43 xmlrpc.php
```

and `ls -l` for `sites/default/files` is

```
[root@localhost default]# pwd
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/default
[root@localhost default]# ls -l
total 28
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 root root 23197 Mar 31 06:43 default.settings.php
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root  4096 Mar 31 06:48 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Fedora uses SELinux for Access Control, maybe you must use `setsebool` & `chcon` commands to change the directory context for SELinux as mentioned here:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/enable-apache-userdir-with-selinux-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/